# case and concatenation, sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

Im using a SQL server database and im having a hard time with my case statement.  What I'm trying to do is insert a concatenation of attributes into an id field (state_issue_teacher_id) when it equals '' (empty field).  The problem is that I have some empty id fields that I need to fill with a unique id that is created by a concatenation of attributes through the case statement.

[image]

The empty rows above I need to fill with a concatenation of last_name+first_name+gender+race_ethnicity_code+high_degree_code+position_code+assignment_code.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT    
        state_issue_teacher_id,
        region_code
        + county_code
        + district_code AS district_code ,
        last_name ,
        first_name ,
        assigned_fte = CASE assign_fte
                  WHEN '' THEN 0
                  ELSE CAST(assign_fte AS NUMERIC(18,
                  2))
                  END ,
        CASE WHEN state_issue_teacher_id = '' THEN 
        RTRIM([last_name]) + '_' + RTRIM([first_name]) + '_' + RTRIM([gender])
        + '_' + RTRIM([race_ethnicity_code]) + '_' + high_degree_code + '_'
        + position_code  + '_' + assignment_code
        ELSE state_issue_teacher_id
        END,
        year_time

FROM      dbo.example
```

Comment: whats the problem? what is the expected output?

Comment: `assigned_fte = CASE.... END,` -> `CASE ... END as assigned_fte,`?

Comment: @AaronLS It's the same thing, I believe.

Comment: If any of the columns used in your concatenation are null, your concatenated value will be null. You might need to use `coalesce` if this is the case.

Comment: @AaronLS why would that matter? That's like `FROM dbo.table AS t` vs. `FROM dbo.table t`.

Comment: Can you define whether "empty field" means empty string or `NULL`? They are quite different.

Comment: What type is state_issue_teacher_id? Does it need an RTrim too?

Comment: its an empty string '' not null.

Comment: state_issue_teacher_id does not need an rtrim

Comment: You have been asked what is the datatype of `state_issue_teacher_id`. It would be good to add the whole `CREATE` table statement.

Comment: What error, or wrong results... fill us in!!!

Comment: all data types in the table are varchar and all attributes in the concatenation are not null.  I'm not getting an error the query runs but the rows remain empty.

Comment: Perhaps if the `state_issue_teacher_id` is empty, the other fields are, too? :)

Comment: @Tone What do you mean "*the rows remain empty*"?  You do realize that this is a SELECT statement and that SELECT statements only return rows, they cannot change them, right?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I thought maybe he was mixing update syntax, thinking this would update the field.  More of a way to emphasize that you can't update a field through a select statement.  Hence "I'm not getting an error the query runs but the rows remain empty." implies he expects an udpate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for everyone that answered the question.  I got it to work with the below query.

```
SELECT    
    state_issue_teacher_id,
    region_code
    + county_code
    + district_code AS district_code ,
    last_name ,
    first_name ,
    gender,
    race_ethnicity_code,
     high_degree_code, 
    position_code,
    assignment_code,  
    assigned_fte = CASE assign_fte
              WHEN '' THEN 0
              ELSE CAST(assign_fte AS NUMERIC(18,
              2))
              END ,
    state_issue_teacher_id =
    CASE state_issue_teacher_id WHEN  '' THEN
    RTRIM([last_name]) + '_' + RTRIM([first_name]) + '_' + RTRIM([gender])
      + '_' + RTRIM([race_ethnicity_code]) + '_' + high_degree_code + '_'
      + position_code  + '_' + assignment_code
      ELSE state_issue_teacher_id
    END,
    year_time
FROM dbo.example
```

Answer (score 2):

When concatenating like that you need to account for two possible problems.

First are all of the fields you are concatenating together varchar (or nvarchar) or are some of them int or numeric? If your datatypes are not varchar or nvarchar, then you need to convert them to use them in a concatentation.

The next possible problem is if one or more of the values can be null. You will need to coalesce any value that could be null with a varchar value  (usually a space or empty string for a concatenations although sometimes the value "unknown" works too))  or the concatenation will return null as null concatenated with anything else is null.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT    
    state_issue_teacher_id,
    region_code
    + county_code
    + district_code AS district_code ,
    last_name ,
    first_name ,
    assigned_fte = CASE assign_fte
              WHEN '' THEN 0
              ELSE CAST(assign_fte AS NUMERIC(18,
              2))
              END ,
    CASE WHEN state_issue_teacher_id = '' THEN 
    RTRIM(coalesce([last_name],'ValueYouUseInsteadOfNull')) + '_' + 
    RTRIM(coalesce([first_name],'ValueYouUseInsteadOfNull')) + '_' + 
    RTRIM(coalesce([gender],'ValueYouUseInsteadOfNull')) + '_' + 
    RTRIM(coalesce([race_ethnicity_code],'ValueYouUseInsteadOfNull')) + '_' + 
    coalesce(high_degree_code,'ValueYouUseInsteadOfNull') + '_' + 
    coalesce(position_code,'ValueYouUseInsteadOfNull')  + '_' + 
    coalesce(assignment_code,'ValueYouUseInsteadOfNull')
    ELSE state_issue_teacher_id
    END,
    year_time
FROM      dbo.example
```

Odds are, you have null in some of those fields.
Give this query a try.

Comment: If it won't run at all, you may be mixing field types.  Use Convert(varchar,<your-not-varchar-stuff-here>) to overcome that.

Answer (score -1):

How about?:

```
update example
set state_issue_teacher_id = 
RTRIM([last_name]) + '_' + RTRIM([first_name]) + '_' + RTRIM([gender])
        + '_' + RTRIM([race_ethnicity_code]) + '_' + high_degree_code + '_'
        + position_code  + '_' + assignment_code
WHERE isnull(state_issue_teacher_id, '') = ''
```

Comment: And I quote "...I have some empty id fields that I need to fill with a unique id"

Comment: mmmkkayy. what about the `SELECT` query that he had in his original question made you think that he was going to need an `UPDATE` statement?